# PostgreSQL psycopg2 Python3.7.4 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, character-encoding, psycopg2

I'm trying to query from a PostgreSQL database with ANSI drivers but for some queries it fails, giving me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the function to set the connection and query:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
def query_cdk_database(query):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="some_host", port = xxx, 
                            database="xxx", user="xxxx",
                            password="xxx", client_encoding ='auto')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    dat = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return dat
```

have to say for the mayority of the queries it works but for some it breaks. Here is one that always breaks:

```
query = u"SELECT * FROM ed.VehicleSales_v"
x = query_cdk_database(query)
```

it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-06ace3c63c62> in <module>
      1 query = u"SELECT * FROM ed.VehicleSales_v;"
----> 2 x = query_raw(query)

<ipython-input-20-6abf4dcf327f> in query_raw(query)
      7     cur = conn.cursor()
      8     cur.execute(query)
----> 9     dat = cur.fetchall()
     10     cur.close()
     11     conn.close()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To solve this problem I have tried the following:

- changing connection parameter "client_encoding" in psycopg2.connect to several different ones.
- looping through all the columns one by one to detect which one returns an error, but individually none return an error.
- convert the query string to unicode or other different codec
- Download the data manually raw from PGAdmin, then read it with pandas, which but with warnings "DtypeWarning: Columns (4,55,70,153) have mixed types" (this could be a separate question)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using package pyodbc.
here:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=adp_report;"
    "UID=db_name;"
    "PWD=password;"
    "SERVER=111.111.11.11;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )
```

note that the "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};" is literally that string. For the other arguments change them accordingly. Here is a handy function to pass the connection string and query from the database.

```
def query_db(query):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    dat = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    conn.close()
    return dat
```